# Find the solution of $~\dfrac{dy}{dt} + \sqrt{1+ t^2}~e^{-t}~y=0$ , $~y(0)=1~.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution of the initial value problem $$\dfrac{dy}{dt} + \sqrt{1+ t^2}~e^{-t}~y=0~ ,~~~ y(0)=1~.$$

It seems like 'separable equation' so I tried 
$$-\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dt} = \sqrt{1+ t^2}~e^{-t} $$

However, righthand side is complicated to integrate, so I think there is another method but I don't know.

How can I  solve this?

Comment: Somehow, I doubt the integral of the right hand side would be elementary.  My guess is the best you can be expected to do is to express the result in terms of that integral.

Comment: @Mike you're right, why didn't i think of it , Thank U!

Comment: @gen-z ready to perish Thank U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, the antiderivative of the rhs is probably impossible to find (even using special functions).

So, if there is no typo in the problem, it is probably a numerical integration task.

However, if the problem was
$$\frac{dy}{dt} + \sqrt{1+ t}\,e^{-t}y=0 \qquad \text{with} \qquad y(0)=1$$ the story would be totally different since
$$\int \sqrt{1+ t}\,e^{-t}\,dt =\frac{e\sqrt{\pi }}{2}   \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{1+t}\right)-e^{-t} \sqrt{1+t}$$

Comment: Thank you for answer!

Comment: Is that something you just know off the top of your head?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish. A very simple change of variable leads to a very well known integration (one IBP is required). To tell the truth, after 60 years in  research, there are a few things I "see" (even being almost blind !). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici To clarify, I didn’t mean that rhetorically to imply you were ‘cheating’ or anything, I mostly meant is that like an identity you’re used to or something

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish. Don't worry ! I took it easy but, as said, you find this class of integrals so often in so many areas that it almost become automatic.